# Movie ident : Boy chased by trolls

Tags: story-identification, magic

This movie isn't too old, it's about a little boy that opens up a book and it cursed him,  his brother and his sister. They went upstairs and a little troll was up there and the troll acts crackers.

Later on in the movie, a lot of trolls were chasing them trying to get the boy's book back because it wasn't supposed to be open.

Please help me find this movie

Comment: Were they big trolls or small trolls? Were they trolls or just troll-like? Do you remember any of the actors? How old were the characters? When did you watch the film, recently?

Comment: Live-action? Cartoon? 3D animation?

Comment: Ernest Scared Stupid?

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/163192/trying-to-find-a-live-action-movie-with-cgi-monsters (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 5):

Could this be "[The Spiderwick Chronicles](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0416236/)"?

The description on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Spiderwick_Chronicles_(film)) matches reasonably well;

> Jared uses the key to open a chest. In it, he finds Spiderwick's field
>   guide to faeries; although an attached note warns him not to read it,
>   he does so anyway.
>
> Lucinda tells them that they need to find Arthur Spiderwick and have
>   him destroy the book; however, Arthur is being held captive by Sylphs,
>   a type of faerie. Suddenly, Mulgarath's goblins attack them and steal
>   several pages from the book before they are driven off. Meanwhile in
>   the woods, Mulgarath berates Redcap violently for not bringing all of
>   the book, but he is pleased by having a page that allows Mulgarth to
>   break the protective circle by moonrise. Mulgarath and Redcap prepare
>   the potion for the upcoming night. Meanwhile on the children's return,
>   Hogsqueal warns them that one of the stolen pages will allow Mulgarath
>   to destroy the protective circle when the moon rises.