# Find a movie with an old house and a glass and wind and magic

Tags: story-identification, movie

I am trying to find a movie. I remember a house on the end of the hill. There was always a wind and an old woman was telling somebody that this wind will blow off the old house. Also there was a small girl, and her father was somehow connected with watches or maybe just a glass. And when girl looked through this glass or watch she could see magic in the world (she saw elves in the forest and some evil beasts).

I remember a path made of salt, that was protecting house from evil spirits And also I guess I remember a swing. Also the atmosphere was like a fairy-tale

Comment: How old is the movie (approximately)? Animation (I presume)?

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/163192/trying-to-find-a-live-action-movie-with-cgi-monsters

Answer (score 5):

Possibly the [Spiderwick Chronicles](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0416236/plotsummary) :

> The Grace boy twins are dragged from New York to the inherited, run-down Spiderwick estate with clueless but bossy elder brat sister Mallory as their divorced mother Helen couldn't afford her old job at city prices. Shy nerd Simon resigns to thinks, but adventurous brother Jason stubbornly revolts, then finds presumably deceased uncle Arthur Spiderwick's life's work 'field guide to the magical world', is stunned when the creatures it generally warns against actually inhabit the estate and explores further. Honey-addicted tiny book guardian Thimbletack, who lives indoors, explains it most at all cost be kept away from ogre Mulgarath and his **army of trolls etcetera**, which a **magical circle** keeps outside, but his clueless siblings draw them there. Rescuing Simon, Jason meets and teams up with bird-eating Hogsqueal. The ensuing battle under siege is the start of further adventures, involving Arthur's mental asylum-bound daughter Lucinda Spiderwick, who divulges more surprises, while the ogre's forces stop at nothing to **conquer he book for control of the magical world**, which Jason gets to penetrate further then he could imagine.

Also :

> Thimbletack gives Jared **the seeing stone**, so he can see invisible creatures. Jared sees short, menacing goblins carrying Simon away.