# Movie: during a weekend in a house, a young kid befriends someone eating anything, they find the place of a plant scientist who reached immortality

Tags: story-identification, movie

There is a family who went to a house for the weekend. The wife and three kids went to that house first, the husband doesn't come on Saturday because of work. He says he will come after the work. The younger seems so attached to his father in that story.

After some time, the younger kid made a friend in those woods who eats literally anything.

And the house they came was a house of scientist, who discovered plant species/ organized the species.

Though I don't remember, that scientist​ attains immortality or like that and he went to another world. That scientist has a daughter who is now quite an old woman.

And there is makeshift villain who is after something that scientist found, but that he didn't get during scientist time, so he is waiting for his time. The scientist secured the perimeter of house with some kind of plants.

I don't remember how story goes on but in the climax, the younger kid got the book and climbs the house. And the villain transforms into some kind of monster and chaseq the kid. The kid with plan of his friend (woods), drops the book and the villain in attempt to catch the book transforms into a bird/crow... He catches the book and flees the scene but only caught by kid's friend, surprisingly. He ate the villain in that form. And the movie ends.

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/163192/trying-to-find-a-live-action-movie-with-cgi-monsters

Answer (score 9):

I'm relatively sure this is *The Spiderwick Chronicles* (2008).

From [IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0416236/):

> Upon moving into the run-down Spiderwick Estate with their mother, twin brothers Jared and Simon Grace, along with their sister Mallory, find themselves pulled into an alternate world full of faeries and other creatures.

More precisely... (All extracts from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Spiderwick_Chronicles_(film)))

**The wife and three kids went to that house first, the husband doesn't come on Saturday because of work.**

Well technically they're divorced and it's not for the weekend, but the wife and three kids match.

> In 2008, recently divorced Helen Grace moves into the now vacant Spiderwick Estate in the woods with her children after she inherits the land from her aunt Lucinda, though twins Jared and Simon and their older sister Mallory do not want to move away from New York.

**The scientist secured the perimeter of house with some kind of plants.**

> He tells Jared about a protective circle that Arthur Spiderwick placed around his house and gives him a stone with a hole through which he can look through in order to see the magical creatures.

**That scientist​ attains immortality or like that and he went to another world. That scientist has a daughter who is now quite an old woman.**

> The children decide to visit their great-aunt Lucinda, now in a psychiatric hospital for claiming her father was abducted by fairies, for advice. [...] Arthur has been held captive by the Sylphs, a type of fairy, for the past 80 years. [...] They meet Arthur, who has not aged and is also unaware of the time he has spent there.

**The kid with plan of his friend (woods), drops the book and the villain in attempt to catch the book transforms into a bird/crow...**

> With no choice, Jared tosses the book into the air, allowing Mulgarath to transform into a raven and manages to catch it, but before he could escape into the forest with it, he is suddenly snatched and devoured by Hogsqueal hidden in a tree.

---

Found by chance, as I never watched the movie but vaguely remembered it having something to do with a book and creatures. (And there were three kids and a book in my recollection of the poster)