# Book where kids find a journal about supernatural entities?

Tags: story-identification, books

The kids moved into a house inherited from a family member. There was a journal one kid found in an attack. The journal detailed a bunch of fantasy, fey-type creatures. The kids had a evilish brownie living in their house. The book was presented as something true that was mailed in to the publisher. There were two series.

Comment: see also https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/163192/trying-to-find-a-live-action-movie-with-cgi-monsters (about the film based on the book)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You say "kids move in some relative's house and find a journal about creatures which turn out to be real" and I hear *The Spiderwick Chronicles* (2003-2009) by Tony DiTerlizzi and Holly Black.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Spiderwick_Chronicles):

> *The Field Guide*, the first book in the series, was published in May 2003. It opens in Maine, where **nine-year-old identical twins Jared and Simon and their thirteen-year-old sister Mallory move into the decrepit Spiderwick Estate with their mother**, Helen. On the first night, they discover a secret library on the second floor using a dumbwaiter. They later discover that the library connects to the rest of the house via a hidden door in a hall closet. **A brownie named Thimbletack, who has lived in the house for years, becomes angry with the Grace children when they destroy his nest inside the walls**, and Jared is blamed for the ensuing havoc wrought by the brownie in retaliation including assaults on Mallory, Simon, and the trashing of the kitchen. Following a clue in the form of a riddle-poem, **Jared finds *Arthur Spiderwick's Field Guide to the Fantastical World Around You* in a secret compartment in a trunk in the attic. The *Field Guide* is an old hand-written and illustrated book with information on different types of faeries in the surrounding forest.** The novel ends as the Grace children make amends with Thimbletack by building him a new home out of an old birdhouse. Thimbletack then warns them that the book which they found is dangerous and was not meant to be in the hands of mortals.

Comment: Thanks I guess I just suck at googling

Comment: @neutraltax We've all been there. :) Don't forget to accept.